# How can I limit mobile data usage for other users(multi-users) of my Android phone

Tags: android, android-12, multi-user, google-pixel, android-data-usage

The other users (like guest or any other, referred as multi-users) of my phone use too much mobile data. I don't want to completely deny the permission to use it but set a limit on it. A limit which doesn't just notify of limit crossing but I want it to forcibly turn the mobile data off at that point.

If that's not possible, then tell me a way to turn the mobile data at a specific time automatically so that I can always be sure that they aren't wasting my data.

Please tell me a solution to this problem.
Device Manufacturer: OnePlus
ROM: Pixel Experience
Android Version: 12